# Rewrite a Python Code

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a `List` of stats (extracted from a raw text) structured like this :

```
list_stats = [u'site1.com', u'3,346', u'23', u'0.68%', u'\u20ac0.04', u'\u20ac0.25', u'\u20ac0.85', u'site2.com', u'45,784', u'243', u'0.56%', u'\u20ac0.34', u'\u20ac0.32', u'\u20ac0.43', u'site3.com', u'9,396', u'432', u'4.54%', u'\u20ac890.24', u'\u20ac9.87', u'\u20ac8.93']
```

I want to have a `Dict` like this :

```
sites = {
    u'site1.com' : [u'3,346', u'23', u'0.68%', u'\u20ac0.04', u'\u20ac0.25'],
    u'site2.com' : [u'45,784', u'243', u'0.56%', u'\u20ac0.34', u'\u20ac0.32'],
    u'site3.com' : [u'9,396', u'432', u'4.54%', u'\u20ac890.24', u'\u20ac9.87', u'\u20ac8.93']
}
```

So far, I've coded this and it's working :

```
sites = {}
for field in list_stats:
    if 'count' not in locals(): count = 0
    if count == 0:
            sites[field] = []
            current = field
    else:
            sites[current].append(field)
    count = count + 1
    if count == 7:
            count = 0
```

However, it doesn't seem to be perfect. I am sure we can come up with something more clean and elegant. Can your recode it better?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com as it doesn't ask a specific question, but asks instead for existing, (mostly) working code to be refactored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version of python supports [dict comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (2.7+)

```
{k: list_stats[i*7+1:(i+1)*7] for i, k in enumerate(list_stats[::7])}
```

Which, in this case, gives

```
{u'site1.com': [u'3,346',
                u'23',
                u'0.68%',
                u'\u20ac0.04',
                u'\u20ac0.25',
                u'\u20ac0.85'],
 u'site2.com': [u'45,784',
                u'243',
                u'0.56%',
                u'\u20ac0.34',
                u'\u20ac0.32',
                u'\u20ac0.43'],
 u'site3.com': [u'9,396',
                u'432',
                u'4.54%',
                u'\u20ac890.24',
                u'\u20ac9.87',
                u'\u20ac8.93']}
```

Comment: yours code has: `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.45 us per loop`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [the modulo operator, `%`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

```
sites = {}
for count, field in enumerate(list_stats):
    if count % 8 == 0:
            sites[field] = []
            current = field
    else:
            sites[current].append(field)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionary comprehension and [itertools.grouper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) solution

```
from itertools import izip_longest
>>> from pprint import PrettyPrinter
>>> pp = PrettyPrinter(indent = 4)
>>> pp.pprint({e[0]: e[1:] for e in izip_longest(*[iter(list_stats)]*7)})
{   u'site1.com': (   u'3,346',
                      u'23',
                      u'0.68%',
                      u'\u20ac0.04',
                      u'\u20ac0.25',
                      u'\u20ac0.85'),
    u'site2.com': (   u'45,784',
                      u'243',
                      u'0.56%',
                      u'\u20ac0.34',
                      u'\u20ac0.32',
                      u'\u20ac0.43'),
    u'site3.com': (   u'9,396',
                      u'432',
                      u'4.54%',
                      u'\u20ac890.24',
                      u'\u20ac9.87',
                      u'\u20ac8.93')}
```

Comment: it should be `*7` not `*6`.

Comment: your solution is the fastest one compared to others: `100000 loops, best of 3: 3.86 us per loop`

Comment: @NamitKewat: Its a known solution. Refer the itertools.grouper recipe mentioned in the link